# Making a VBA FOR loop using vlookup function in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use a Vlookup function 47 times to get the value for every data. I call the table I am filling "Table 1". "Table 1 starts from E3. I would like to use the vlookup to find the value for cell E3 and fill it in F3.

I call the table from which I return value by Vlookup "Table2". "Table 2 is located in sheet "CC Name" and has two columns A and B.

I have tried two FOR Loops. One FOR Loop for the Vlookup function to be repeated 47 times. Second FOR Loop for the Name of the vlookup function "ccName" to use the function to fill the value in "Table 1" for 43 times, but I get error every time I implement the Code.

```
Sub GLcreation()

For n = 3 To 50
For c = 3 To 50

ccName(c) = WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Range("E" & n), Worksheets("CC Name").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)

Range("F" & n) = ccName(c)

Next c
Next n

End Sub
```

If you can Show me how to Code the correct for Loop, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Get rid of the c loop and just do `Range("F" & n) = WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Range("E" & n), Worksheets("CC Name").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as there is a non-match the code will fail. It's safer to test for match before making the lookup. Here is a better solution:

```
Sub GLcreation()

Dim n As Integer
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = WorksheetFunction

For n = 3 To 50
    If wf.CountIf(Worksheets("CC Name").Range("A:A"), Range("E" & n).Value) > 0 Then
        Range("F" & n).Value = wf.Index(Worksheets("CC Name").Range("B:B"), wf.Match(Range("E" & n).Value, Worksheets("CC Name").Range("A:A"), 0))
    End If
Next n

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

By getting rid of c Loop, the correct Code is:

```
Range("F" & n) = WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Range("E" & n), Worksheets("CC Name").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
```